# How to correct install PSCyr font in Linux?

Tags: fonts, installing, linux

How to correct install PSCyr font on Linux?

I try to install it in `~/.texmf-var` but this doesn't help.

And into local tree: `/usr/local/share/texmf` - nothing.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/19384) No need to add thanks, simply upvote any good answers you may receive.

Comment: We'll need more detail of what you actually did to help here: font installation requires several steps, depending on the format the font is supplied in.